# Creating a class of objects from a group of functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oop, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm *very* new to OOP, and want to start getting in the habit of writing modular, reusable code. Sorry for the wall of code and text, just trying to give as much context and be as clear as possible.

I have defined a series of functions, all which act on a pandas DataFrame, and I wish to create a class from this series of functions. I thought it would be a good idea to create a class because I will be using this code on DataFrames that are pretty standard going forward.

My question is twofold:
1. Should I be using OOP concepts and design for this problem
2. What the hell is causing my darn code to break?!

Thanks in advance everyone!

Below are the functions I have defined:

```
def __describe(df, col):
    df_desc = df[col].describe()
    return df_desc

def __sort_by_character_study_day(df):        
    new_index_values = df.index.levels[0].str.split().str[-1].astype(int)
    df.index = df.index.set_levels(new_index_values, level='study_day')
    df = df.sort_index()
    return df

def change_from_baseline(df, col):
    df_sorted = sort_df(df = df, by = ["Animal_id", "ord"])
    groupedf = grouper(df=df_sorted, by='Animal_id')
    df_sorted['Change From Baseline'] = df_sorted[col] - groupedf[col].transform('first')
    df_sorted['Percent Change From Baseline'] = (df_sorted['Change From Baseline'] / groupedf[col].transform('first')).round(4) * 100
    return df_sorted

def grouper(df, by):
    df = df.groupby(by)
    return df

def sns_box_plot(df, col, y_lab):   
    plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    g = sns.boxplot(x="study_day", y = col, hue="group_c", 
                    data = df, palette='rainbow', 
                    hue_order=["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"])
    plt.ylabel(y_lab, fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel("Study Day", fontsize=20)
    plt.tick_params('both', labelsize='14')
    plt.show()

def sns_bar_plot(df, col, y_lab):       
    plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    g = sns.barplot(x="study_day", y = col, hue="group_c", 
                    data = df, palette='rainbow')
    plt.ylabel(y_lab, fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel("Study Day", fontsize=20)
    plt.tick_params('both', labelsize='14')
    plt.show()

def sort_df(df, by):
    df = df.sort_values(by)
    return df   

def summary_stats(df, by, col):
    dfgrouped = grouper(df, by)
    df_desc = __describe(dfgrouped, col)
    df_summ = pd.DataFrame()
    df_summ["count"] = df_desc['count']
    df_summ["mean"] = df_desc['mean'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["std"] = df_desc['std'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["25%"] = df_desc['25%'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["50%"] = df_desc['50%'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["75%"] = df_desc['75%'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["min"] = df_desc['min'].round(2).astype(str)
    df_summ["max"] = df_desc['max'].round(2).astype(str)
    return __sort_by_character_study_day(df_summ)

def summary_stat_formatted(df, by, col):
    data_summ = summary_stats(df, by, col)
    formatted_summ = pd.DataFrame()
    formatted_summ["Number of Observations"] = data_summ['count'].astype(int)
    formatted_summ["Mean (SD)"] = data_summ["mean"] +' (' + data_summ["std"] +')'
    formatted_summ["Median (25th - 75th %ile)"] = data_summ["50%"] + ' (' + data_summ["25%"] +' ,' + data_summ["75%"] +')'  
    formatted_summ["Min, Max"] = data_summ["min"] +' ,' + data_summ["max"]
    return formatted_summ

def write_to_excel(df, outfile, sheetname):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfile, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)
```

When I call one of the functions, say:

```
summary_stats(df=bw, by= ["study_day", "group_c"], col='Body_Weight')
```

Everything works as expected, I get the following output:
[image]

Now, since I will be using these same functions on nearly identical DataFrames (only thing different is the name of the dataframe and the analysis column), I thought it might be a good idea to create a class (**please let me know if this is the right approach**). My class looks like this:

```
class PreClinicalData(object):

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __describe(self, col):
        df_desc = self.df[col].describe()
        return df_desc

    def __sort_by_character_study_day(self):
        new_index_values = self.df.index.levels[0].str.split().str[-1].astype(int)
        self.df.index = self.df.index.set_levels(new_index_values, level='study_day')
        self.df = self.df.sort_index()
        return self.df

    def change_from_baseline(self,  col):
        df_sorted = self.sort_df(df = self.df, by = ["Animal_id", "ord"])
        groupedf = self.grouper(df=df_sorted, by='Animal_id')
        df_sorted['Change From Baseline'] = df_sorted[col] - groupedf[col].transform('first')
        df_sorted['Percent Change From Baseline'] = (df_sorted['Change From Baseline'] / groupedf[col].transform('first')).round(4) * 100
        return df_sorted

    def summary_stats(self, by, col):
        dfgrouped = self.grouper(df=self.df, by=by)
        df_desc = self.__describe(dfgrouped, col=col)
        df_summ = pd.DataFrame()
        df_summ["count"] = df_desc['count']
        df_summ["mean"] = df_desc['mean'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["std"] = df_desc['std'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["25%"] = df_desc['25%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["50%"] = df_desc['50%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["75%"] = df_desc['75%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["min"] = df_desc['min'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["max"] = df_desc['max'].round(2).astype(str)
        return self.__sort_by_character_study_day(df_summ)

    def summary_stat_formatted(self, by, col):
        data_summ = self.summary_stats(self, by, col)
        formatted_summ = pd.DataFrame()
        formatted_summ["Number of Observations"] = data_summ['count'].astype(int)
        formatted_summ["Mean (SD)"] = data_summ["mean"] +' (' + data_summ["std"] +')'
        formatted_summ["Median (25th - 75th %ile)"] = data_summ["50%"] + ' (' + data_summ["25%"] +' ,' + data_summ["75%"] +')'  
        formatted_summ["Min, Max"] = data_summ["min"] +' ,' + data_summ["max"]
        return formatted_summ

    def write_to_excel(self, outfile, sheetname):
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfile, engine='xlsxwriter')
        self.df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)    

    def grouper(self, by):
        return self.df.groupby(by)

    def sns_box_plot(self, col, y_lab):   
        plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
        sns.set_style("whitegrid")
        g = sns.boxplot(x="study_day", y = col, hue="group_c", 
                        data = self.df, palette='rainbow', 
                        hue_order=["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"])
        plt.ylabel(y_lab, fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel("Study Day", fontsize=20)
        plt.tick_params('both', labelsize='14')
        plt.show()

    def sns_bar_plot(self, col, y_lab):       
        plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
        sns.set_style("whitegrid")
        g = sns.barplot(x="study_day", y = col, hue="group_c", 
                        data = self.df, palette='rainbow')
        plt.ylabel(y_lab, fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel("Study Day", fontsize=20)
        plt.tick_params('both', labelsize='14')
        plt.show()

    def sort_df(self, by):
        return self.df.sort_values(by)   

    def summary_stats(self, by, col):
        dfgrouped = self.grouper(self, by)
        df_desc = self.__describe(dfgrouped, col)
        df_summ = pd.DataFrame()
        df_summ["count"] = df_desc['count']
        df_summ["mean"] = df_desc['mean'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["std"] = df_desc['std'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["25%"] = df_desc['25%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["50%"] = df_desc['50%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["75%"] = df_desc['75%'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["min"] = df_desc['min'].round(2).astype(str)
        df_summ["max"] = df_desc['max'].round(2).astype(str)
        return self.__sort_by_character_study_day(df_summ)

    def summary_stat_formatted(self, by, col):
        data_summ = self.summary_stats(self, by, col)
        formatted_summ = pd.DataFrame()
        formatted_summ["Number of Observations"] = data_summ['count'].astype(int)
        formatted_summ["Mean (SD)"] = data_summ["mean"] +' (' + data_summ["std"] +')'
        formatted_summ["Median (25th - 75th %ile)"] = data_summ["50%"] + ' (' + data_summ["25%"] +' ,' + data_summ["75%"] +')'  
        formatted_summ["Min, Max"] = data_summ["min"] +' ,' + data_summ["max"]
        return formatted_summ

    def write_to_excel(self, outfile, sheetname):
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfile, engine='xlsxwriter')
        self.df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)
```

I can instantiate an instance of the class as follows:

```
bodyweight = PreClinicalData(chickv_data['bodyweight'])
```

And I am able to call the DataFrame and use the `head()` method just fine.:

```
bodyweight.df.head()
```

Now, when I call the same method as shown above...I get the following:

```
bodyweight.summary_stats(by = ["study_day", "group_c"], col = "Body_Weight")
```

which yields the following error:

[image]

I have no clue where these alleged three arguments are coming from?!

Comment: Monkey-patch instead of defining an entire new class that you have to initiate (again) with a df: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation

Comment: Don't pass `self` to `grouper`: it's just `self.grouper(by)`. if you pass `self` it will get `self`(automatically) then `self`, then `by`, hence the 3 args.

Comment: @user3471881 - that worked just fine, thank you! I'm really looking to get some feedback on how to write this as a class. Any help there would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @progmatico -that one still doesn't work for me. Do you think its a good idea to have grouper like I do, or should I just do the grouping as part of the method?

Comment: Why are you using double-underscore name-mangling, e.g. `__describe`? Do you *want* double-underscore name-mangling, i.e., you suspect your class will be subclasses and want to hide the `__describe` method? Or, did you read somewhere that `__` is "private" in Python?

Comment: How exactly did `self.grouper(by)` not work?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Hi, thanks for responding. Yup read somewhere that `__` meant private, thought it would apply here. I actually ended up removing those methods and updated the code. It seems to be working now! Only thing now is `__sort_by_character_study_day` is throwing `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'`. Time to go wrap my head around that...

Comment: So, very important to understand, *python does not have private/public variables*. If you want to let other developers know that an attribute is nnot part of the public api, conventionally you use a *single* underscore. That being said, I am surprised that fixed your issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks for that info! What I ended up doing was just getting rid of the those `__describe()` and `grouper()` methods and just called the respective `describe()`  and `groupby()` methods on the dataframe in the `summary_stats()` method. Do you think this a better way than what is posted in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184357/discussion-between-thecuriouslycodingfoxah-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Comment: I still don't understand why you would put these methods in a class. From what I can see now, your class is just a container for different functions that 1) would work just as well being spaghetti code or 2) stand-alone functions. Putting them in a class is overkill and just makes everything confusing.

Comment: Think about `PreclinicalData(df).sns_box_plot('y', 'y-label')`. Why is this better than `sns_box_plot(df, 'y', 'y-label')`?

Comment: @user3471881 - thanks for this input. That's exactly what I wanted to know, if making it a class makes sense. I think will keep it as functions and use monkey-patching. It seems to work exactly how I want it to, and is more clear. Thanks again!